# Error in Push notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification

Here i got another problem regarding  the `push notification`,it works perfectly in `emulator` but not working in `device`.

code:for the `GCMIntentService`

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService{
public GCMIntentService(){
super(Constants.SenderId);
}
@Override
protected void onError(Context context, String regId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("insideerroe");
Log.e("", "error registration id : "+regId);
}
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String regId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
// Log.e(“”, “registration id : “+regId);
System.out.println("inside on registration");

handleRegistration(getApplicationContext(), regId);



}
@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String regId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
private void handleRegistration(Context context, String regId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Log.e("", "registration id : "+regId);
}


}
```

and the below code:

```
public class Androidpushnotification extends Activity {




@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
if (regId.equals("")) {
GCMRegistrar.register(this, Constants.SenderId);
}

else {
Log.v("", "Already registered: "+regId);

}
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

manifest file:

```
    <!-- GCM connects to Internet Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.androidpushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.androidpushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission
  android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Androidpushnotification"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.androidpushnotification" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>
```

Could anybody help me regarding this ,Thanks

Comment: What about manifest permissions ?

Comment: @Rstar i have added that too

Comment: @Rstar could you help me regarding this..

Comment: yes but i think code looks like correct

Comment: @Rstar yes..me too think like that but why its not working in device

Comment: @Rstar can u help regarding this problem

Comment: What's not working in device?  Does the registration work?  Do you get the device registration id? Does the server send the message to gcm server?  If it does, what's the response?

Comment: @priya2134412 what is the error? if you are not sure about error, put logs at registration process and in IntentService... this might help you to find your buggy snippet..

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem is of Android OS version. I have faced same issue and found that Its only working with the OS version >= 4.1.

So, You might be testing it with Emulator version >= 4.1. and your device might be lower than os version 4.1.

Please check/test it with device with version 4.1 OR higher than that. You will find it working.

In-short, your code is right and its working code.

FYI: I think this issue occurs after 15th April,2013. and I have still not get any workaround for it.

If you/anyone find something in same direction then please share it with us.

Thanks,
- Umang Kathiyara